# Displaying the image from webservice(SOAP) in listview

Tags: android, web-services, soap, c#-3.0

I need to access Image from webservice in my android application. I wrote webservice which converts image to string. now I need to access that image in Listview. In which format do I need to access in android.
Please do needfull
Thank you.

Comment: the same format you use in your webservice

Comment: but I have image data type it is returning base64binary in webservice then how to convert it to string base64 in android. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

then decode it with base64 library. get your soap result with primitive soap

```
SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
String result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
if (result != "") {
  byte[] bloc = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);         
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc,0,bloc.length);
}
```

Comment: if I use soapPrimitive then how can I get entity names which are present in that method........ thank you